# Option value are not getting assigned to an variable correctly

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code that worked prior to Swift 3 and after I upgraded to Swift 3, It doesn't work right

```
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components([.hour, .minute], from: currentDate)
    let hour = components.hour
    let minutes = components.minute
    var time = String(describing: hour)  + ":" + String(describing: minutes)
    var newTime = time.components(separatedBy: ":")
    var ihh = Int(newTime[0])
    var imm = Int(newTime[1])

    var shh = String(ihh!)
    var smm = String(imm!)
```

newTime array has 2 option values in it and I did validate that with debugger.
However after the values are assigned to ihh, imm, I see that both of them (ihh, imm) are nil.
Any idea how to fix this?

Borna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var time = String(hour! )  + ":" + String(minutes! )

'Describing ' adds "optional" word into your string

Comment: `Describing` is not the reason.

Comment: @vadian i faced the same issue while migrating frpm swift 2 into swift 3.i really know that 'describing' constructor creates unwanted prefiz and suffix

Comment: @vadian you have wrote nearly the same

Comment: No, not the same, the cause of the error are the optional date components which were non-optionals in Swift 2.

Answer (score 1):

All date components  – by the way, `components` has been changed to `dateComponents` in Swift 3, that avoids also the cast to `NSCalendar` – are optionals in Swift 3 (unlike non-optionals in Swift 2), you have to unwrap them.

The error occurs because a literal like `"Optional(15)"` cannot be converted to `Int`.

```
let hour = components.hour!
let minutes = components.minute!
```