# Concatenate two int in swift

Tags: swift

I try to concatenate two integer values (current hour and current minute of time). 
For example:

```
int1: 18
int2: 2
```

Then I want them to be one int: `182`. 
I get the current hour and current minute with this code:

```
// get the current date and time
    let currentDateTime = Date()

    // get the user's calendar
    let userCalendar = Calendar.current

    // choose which date and time components are needed
    let requestedComponents: Set<Calendar.Component> = [
        .year,
        .month,
        .day,
        .hour,
        .minute,
        .second
    ]

    // get the components
    let dateTimeComponents = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponents, from: currentDateTime)

    // now the components are available
    let dtHour = dateTimeComponents.hour   
    let dtMinute = dateTimeComponents.minute
```

Then I thought that I could concat those two integers when I converted them into a string and than back to int so that I have the big int value. I have done this with the following lines:

```
let strHour = String(describing: dtHour)
    let strMinute = String(describing: dtMinute)

    var currenttime : String = strHour
    currenttime += strMinute

    //reconvert to int
    let ct: Int? = Int(currenttime)

    print("currentTime as Int   : ", ct)
    print("currenttime as String: ", currenttime)
```

The output of the first print is:

> currentTime as Int   :  nil

And the output of the second print is:

> currenttime as String:  Optional(18)Optional(2)

Yeah I Know that I have to fix the problem with the minutes if the current minute is lower than ten that I have to insert a zero at first but I don't get it why I cannot convert the string back to int so that it is a large string.

So is there a right way to concatenate two integers and then reconvert them back to one single, large int value?

Comment: All properties of `DateComponents` are *optionals,* compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362516/option-value-are-not-getting-assigned-to-an-variable-correctly.

Comment: Remark: Using `String(describing:)` is often the wrong solution. It makes your code compile, but the result is not what you really want.

Comment: And of course you don't need any string conversion: `let ct = dateTimeComponents.hour! * 100 + dateTimeComponents.minute!`

Comment: I'd suggest that you want to rethink converting the concatenated value to an integer. It's not a number: it's a sequence of digits. Just leave it as a string.

Comment: @MartinR I'm slightly doubting whether the OP knows himself what he wants with his format, but note that using a fixed multiplier `100` for the hours yields a format different from the OPs for minutes in the range `0..<10`; e.g. `1802` for the OPs example, rather than `182`.

Comment: @dfri: OP states *"I Know that I have to fix the problem with the minutes if the current minute is lower than ten that I have to insert a zero"*, so he is aware of that issue (I think).

Comment: @MartinR Ah, my bad, I missed that!

Comment: @Fabian Based on your statement that you need to add a zero shouldn't your question state that you want the result to be `1802` and not `182`?

Comment: Thanks for all the input! The answer from @Andrew just works fine. I just added some code to insert a zero if the minute is lower than ten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below prints:

currentTime as Int   :  2249

currenttime as String:  2249

```
    // get the current date and time
    let currentDateTime = Date()

    // get the user's calendar
    let userCalendar = Calendar.current

    // choose which date and time components are needed
    let requestedComponents: Set<Calendar.Component> = [
        .year,
        .month,
        .day,
        .hour,
        .minute,
        .second
    ]

    // get the components
    let dateTimeComponents = userCalendar.dateComponents(requestedComponents, from: currentDateTime)

    // now the components are available
    let dtHour = dateTimeComponents.hour   
    let dtMinute = dateTimeComponents.minute

    let strHour = String(dtHour!.description)
    let strMinute = String(dtMinute!.description)

    var currenttime : String = strHour!
    currenttime += strMinute!

    //reconvert to int
    let ct = Int(currenttime)

    print("currentTime as Int   : ", ct!)
    print("currenttime as String: ", currenttime)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfect! I just added some code to insert a zero if the minute is < 10